# Как получить установленный автором максимальный балл за задание в Google Forms с Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Пишу программу с Google Apps Script, которая пробегает через гугл форму и сравнивает балл, полученный респондентом за каждый вопрос, с максимальным установленным баллом за этот вопрос. То есть пусть за вопрос установлен максимальный балл 2, я с помощью следующего кода узнаю, сколько баллов набрал конкретный человек на этом вопросе:

```
    var formResponse = formResponses[i];

    var itemResponses = formResponse.getGradableItemResponses();
    var  resp = itemResponses.map(item => item.getResponse());
    var  scores = itemResponses.map(item => item.getScore());
```

А как узнать, максимальный балл, который пользователь мог получить за этот вопрос (в нашем случае - 2)?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете взять значения очков из самой Формы

```js
  const form = FormApp.openById('ABCD1234');
  const item = form.getItems()[0].asTextItem();
  if (item.getPoints)
    console.log(item.getPoints());
```

Когда вы перебираете ответы, то можете получить индекс элемента из цикла. Что-то вроде

```js
itemResponses
  .map((item, i) => {
    console.log(`Индекс элемента ${i}`);
    return item.getScore()
  });
```